# change 'isenabled' for wpf texbox in usercontrol (codebehind)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, textbox, isenabled

**Code in context**

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        edit();
    }

    public void edit()
    {

        textBox1.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox2.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox3.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox4.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox5.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox6.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox7.IsEnabled = true;            
        textBox8.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox9.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox10.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox11.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox12.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox13.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox14.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox15.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox16.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox17.IsEnabled = true;
        textBox18.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

I want perform the above using a simple *for loop* that loops through 1-18.

I have tried the followng method but doesn't work as intended

```
    for(i=0;i<19;i++)
    {
          textBox"" + i + "".IsVisible = true;
    }
```

I'm new to wpf and i'm migrating my app from winforms to wpf.

Comment: Would it work in WinForms? I see some strange syntax `textBox"" + i + "".IsVisible = true;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use binding.

XAML (MyUserControl):

```
<UserControl Name="MyControl" ...
....

    <TextBox Name="textBox1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=AreTextBoxesEnabled}" ... />
    <TextBox Name="textBox2" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=AreTextBoxesEnabled}" ... />
    <TextBox Name="textBox3" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=AreTextBoxesEnabled}" ... />
...
```

Code-behind (MyUserControl):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AreTextBoxesEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "AreTextBoxesEnabled",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(MyUserControl));

public bool AreTextBoxesEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(AreTextBoxesEnabledProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AreTextBoxesEnabledProperty, value); }
}
```

Just calling `AreTextBoxesEnabled = true;` will make all the textboxes enabled.

Of course, there are many many other ways. But this is the basic way (without MVVM) of doing it, by harnessing the power of binding.

Simple solution (but not recommended) way is as simple as:

```
for (i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
    var tb = this.FindName("textBox" + i.ToString()) as TextBox;
    if (tb != null) tb.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, binding is a more natural solution for WPF

Comment: changing `DataContext` in a UserControl is a bad idea. `DataContext` is user data. much better use RelativeSource or ElementName for IsEnabled binding, or TemplateBinding in ControlTemplate

Comment: @ASh Agreed, I had that problem before haha.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of text boxes like:

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
```

// Btw, I don't have a compiler by hand, I assume the type is TextBox.

Fill textBoxes:

```
textBoxes.Add(textBox1);
textBoxes.Add(textBox2);
...
textBoxes.Add(textBox18);
```

This is a one-time manual action to fill it. Afterwards you can loop through them:

```
foreach (var textBox in textBoxes)
{
    textBox.IsVisible = true;
}
```

Or use any other setting/algorithm on the text boxes with the foreach loop (or for, linq etc).